# Flex childrens in columns, stretch other childrens

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I have included a Codepen to show where I am and what I'm trying to achieve.

http://codepen.io/pier-philip/pen/ORoopA

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row l-flex">
        <!-- START COL 6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="greybox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Title of the box</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row l-flex">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row l-flex-children">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="statbox">
                                    <div class="absolute-center">
                                        <h3>Revelant data</h3>
                                        <p>Today</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="statbox">
                                    <div class="absolute-center">
                                        <h3>Data</h3>
                                        <p>Filler text</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END COL 6 -->
        <!-- START COL 6 -->
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="greybox">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <h2>Title of the box</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                  <div class="row l-flex">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="row l-flex-children">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="statbox">
                                    <div class="absolute-center">
                                        <h3>Revelant data</h3>
                                        <p>Today</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="statbox">
                                    <div class="absolute-center">
                                        <h3>Data</h3>
                                        <p>Filler text</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END COL 6 -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my SCSS:

```
.l-flex {
    display: flex;
    > [class*='col-'] {
        flex: 1;
    }
}

.l-flex-children {
    display: flex;
    > [class*='col-'] {
        display: flex;
        > * {
            flex: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I need the childrens to stretch to the height of their container. If one statbox stretch because of his content I want all of them to have the same height.

EDIT: Can I provide more information? I've been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now and I still haven't found a compelling answer.

Comment: with the current layout you got, not without javascript